# Does Bell’s theorem assume realism? If so, what kind of realism, philosophically?

Tags: quantum-physics, realism, anti-realism, measurement-theory, panpsychism

This is a philosophical question. It deals with the physics that raise this question. I cite the very recent article by Philip Goff in Scientific American which explains its relevance.

Bell’s theorem involves a set of inequalities that must not be broken if there are variables within entangled particles that determine properties of those particles in a determined state. Since the predictions of quantum mechanics break these conditions and inequalities, it is proposed that local, hidden variables cannot explain the results we see.

There is a relation here to quantum entanglement and the free will theorem of Conway and Kochen. Quantum entanglement has been cited as an example of consciousness at the quantum level by panpsychists. Some panpsychists further argue that panpsychism is not idealism or anti-realism, but a  form of realism involving the matter-consciousness nature of reality.

Crucially, this all depends upon the assumption that the properties the particles hold are independent of measurement and how we measure things. But what justification do we have of making this assumption? After all, at least intuitively, **if** there was a world in reality that was dependent on measurement, it would surely be in the micro scale where perhaps the very act of measurements themselves may introduce hidden variables

If we cannot rule out measurements (of any kind) not affecting these proposed variables, then how can we rule out local, hidden variables? This seems like a pretty massive, and yet seemingly unjustified, assumption to make.

I would recommend reading panpsychists authors, such as William Seager, Philip Goff, Timothy Sprigge, and Annaka Harris.

Comment: If you are familiar with the question of hidden parameters and the context and statement of Bell's inequality it would be helpful to start your question with a precise introduction into this field. But possibly the whole subject is better discussed at Physics SE.

Comment: I agree with Jo, this is not a philosophical question.

Comment: What do "measurements not disturbing the actual system" have to do with "properties the particles hold are independent of measurement"? Measurements can get disturbed all they want while the particles still have independent properties. Who is making "this assumption" and where did you get it from? If this is supposed to refer to ruling out what Bell called superdeterminism your formulation is not even close.

Comment: @Conifold I suppose I should have phrased things more clearly in all honesty. My question was moreso about how one can conclude the assumption of realism, that is the assumption that hidden properties exist independent of measurement.

Comment: @thinkingman I think you will get much better answers on Physics SE - you're getting into pretty technical territory here

Comment: Have voted to reopen, because I don't thinj they will discuss the philosophical implications of realism & localism & challenges to them there. This is absolutely a topic for philosophy, even though it requires physics knowledge - just like the Measurement Problem

Comment: This question should remain closed because it does not demonstrate a sufficient understanding of the problem.  The short answer is that if the "variables" are associated with the measurement devices, then the theory is non-local; a fact that is pretty clear if one is seriously engaged with Bell's theorem and related experiments.

Comment: How is it non local if the measurement devices are locally interacting with the particles?

Comment: @thinkingman I think you are illustrating Dave's point.  The measurement devices are interacting locally with the particle, but that doesn't mean that the particle's behaviour is *completely* determined by that measurement alone.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial What if what we measure is simply not correct in the sense that our measurements are wrong? Maybe it is still determined by some local law that we just don’t know of. The experimental tests that validate Bell’s theorem are tests based on measurements, but that would assume the measurements are correct.

Comment: @thinkingman "What if what we measure is simply not correct in the sense that our measurements are wrong? " sorry, responding to someone pointing out a potential error by asking an unrelated question seems like evasion and is not the way productive discussion is conducted.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial As you said, it’s a potential error. I don’t see the error. I didn’t make the claim that measurement devices affecting hidden variables is non local. He did. It is his responsibility to show how, not mine to show why not. I don’t see how it is non local given that measurement devices affecting a particle would be a local interaction.

Comment: @thinkingman "It is his responsibility to show how" he did, read the paper.  The onus is not on him to explain advanced phsyics to the layman to their satisfaction.  The onus is on you to make a reasonable effort, which includes engaging constructively with criticism.  I'll leave it there.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial I’m talking about Dave, not Bell, so you should pay more attention to things. And the paper doesn’t say that measurement devices affecting particles would be a non local hidden variable theory. Please cite where he does so before complaining about what’s constructive or not.

Comment: @thinkingman "the paper" proves my point.  There has been a lot more work in this area than whichever specific paper you are referring.

Comment: Please show me, in whatever paper you’re talking about, where it implies that the measurement device affecting the result of an experiment is a non local hidden variable theory. Otherwise you’re creating empty points

Comment: @thinkingman  I'd suggest that you read _The Meaning of Quantum Theory_ Baggot 1992 or _Making Sense of Quantum Mechanics_ Bricmont 2016 (especially Ch. 4)

Comment: I must say that I love the way that Thinkingman doesn't take anything lying down. Well done, that man, for standing up for yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's late, so I am tired and apt to make mistakes, but I think that even if the measurement devices are affecting the results of experiments (and by the way, they do), the difficulty with trying to explain entanglement that way is that two or more different sets of measuring devices would have to be affecting measurements in a precisely corrected way which is hard to account for in the experiments that have been performed. Entanglement has been demonstrated now at a distance of over 200km, and experiments have suggested that if the outcome of an experiment on one particle in an entangled pair is to affect the outcome of the other, then a signal would have to pass between the two at around a thousand times the speed of light. So either you can assume non-locality or some form of effect that propagates at a speed we thought was impossible. Admittedly that assumes that the measurements on the two particles are independent (ie that the two sets of measuring devices being used are not inadvertently correlated in some way to produce a misleading result) but I am happy to trust the experimentalists, who know far more about what they are doing than I do. TBH I also imagine that the various tests of Bell's inequalities, and the ramifications of them, have probably been studied to death by people much more clever and meticulous than I am, so I'm inclined not to bother second guessing them.

Comment: Yeah those are all great points. The correlation thing you just mentioned was something I thought of while also trying to sleep last night although at that time the question was still closed.